# Safety of using an empty reference instance across multiple threads

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, concurrency

### Background

I have a class `Data` that stores multiple input parameters and a single output value.

The output value is recalculated whenever one of the input parameters is mutated.

The calculation takes a non-trivial amount of time so it is performed asynchronously.

If one of the input parameters changes during recalculation, the current calculation is cancelled, and a new one is begun.

The cancellation logic is implemented via a serialized queue of calculation operations and a key (reference instance) (`Data.key`). `Data.key` is set to a new reference instance every time a new recalculation is added to the queue. Also only a single recalculation can occur at a time — due to the queue. Any executing recalculation constantly checks if it was the most recently initiated calculation by holding a reference to both the key that what was created with it when it was initiated and the currently existing key. If they are different, then a new recalculation has been queued since it began, and it will terminate.

This will trigger the next recalculation in the queue to begin, repeating the process.

### The basis for my question

The reassignment of `Data.key` is done on the main thread.

The current calculation constantly checks to see if its key is the same as the current one. This means another thread is constantly accessing `Data.key`.

### Question(s)

Is it safe for me to leave `Data.key` vulnerable to being read/written to at the same time?

Is it even possible for a property to be read and written to simultaneously?

Comment: For what I understand in this particular case, there is no problem, since you are accessing the property over and over it's not really importante if your property is not up-to-date to this particular cycle. There is a good explanation on how conflicting access are managed in swift 4 and up here : https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md and https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md

Comment: @shoe
recalculation is a loop?
like this  
```
repeat {
    // some heavy synchronous code, for example converting NSData to UIImage
} while taskKey == currentKey
```

Comment: @Mark Pretty much. Except the `===` operator is used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Data.Key vulnerable to being read/written to at the same time.
Here is example were i'm write key from main thread and read from MySerialQueue.
If you run that code, sometimes it would crash.
Crash happens because of dereference of pointer that point to memory released during writing by main queue.
Xcode have feature called ThreadSanitizer, it would help to catch such problems.
[Discussion About Race condition](https://forums.swift.org/t/will-updating-value-type-variable-concurrently-or-from-multiple-threads-cause-crash/32430)

```
func experiment() {
    var key = MyClass()
    var key2 = MyClass()
    
    class MyClass {}
    
    func writer() {
        for _ in 0..<1000000 {
            key = MyClass()
        }
    }
    
    func reader() {
        for _ in 0..<1000000 {
            if key === key2 {}
        }
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.init(label: "MySerialQueue").async {
        print("reader begin")
        reader()
        print("reader end")
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("writer begin")
        writer()
        print("writer end")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Q:
Is it safe for me to leave Data.key vulnerable to being read/written to at the same time?
A:
No

Q:
Is it even possible for a property to be read and written to simultaneously?
A:
Yes, create a separate queue for the Data.Key that only through which you access it. As long as any operation (get/set) is restricted within this queue you can read or write from anywhere with thread safety.